# View page source code - Where is the code located for PRODUCTS to edit manually

Tags: plugins

Ive installed YoastSEO plug in and that adds Schema markup to the pages, but when i deactivated the plug in the schema markup is still there, wen i click "view page source code"

Where in WordPress is the source code for the PRODUCTS i want to manually remove this section of schema mark up from my PRODUCTS listings